# Network thread which must live as long as the application is on the screen

Tags: android, lifecycle

In my application I have to connect to a server, I’m doing this in a separate thread, and I want that the connection stays active as long as any activity of my application is visible on the screen. I also want that if the user leave my application, the thread is interrupted and the connection is closed.

The main problem here is that if the user rotate the screen, the current activity is destroyed and I cannot distinguish this situation from a situation where the user is really leaving my activity. The method `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` does not work because it is called after `onStop()`, and I want to shut down the connection in `onStop()`.

I also tried a bound service but the problem is exactly the same, the service is shut down when I rotate the screen.

And I do not want to handle the configuration change myself.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onUserLeaveHint()` method did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I know it contradicts a bit your statement that you don't want to handle the configuration change yourself, but if you add

```
<activity android:name="org.example.Activity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

to your Manifest, the lifecycle methods should not get called. If you don't override the onConfigurationChanged() method, no special handling is needed from your side and everything is taken care of by the super class.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the dev guide says this should only be used as a last resort, so I’d rather not use this solution.

Comment: @Guillaume Personally, I would consider this case one of this: "_In some special cases, you may want to bypass restarting of your activity based on one or more types of configuration changes._" (From [the Activity Lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges)) However, if there is another more elegant solution to it, I'd like to hear about it, since I faced similar problems a few times and always resorted to using the above method.

Comment: I can see another solution, but this is perhaps a little ugly. When every activity is stopped, start a timer (e.g. of 10 seconds) in the thread and if every activity is still stopped when the timer is over, interrupt the thread. The nice side effect is that it allows the user to quit the applications a few seconds (for example to read a SMS) without deconnecting it.